# Django REST framework: SearchFilter doesn't work with 2 and more values in search bar if they are from the same field

Tags: django, search, django-rest-framework, filtering

I use SearchFilter to search for therapists:

```
class TherapistSearchListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
search_fields = ['first_name',
                 'therapist_profile__skills__title',
                 'therapist_profile__counselling_areas__title']
filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
queryset = Therapist.objects.all()
serializer_class = TherapistSearchSerializer
```

Generally It works great (searches even when user enters several values from **different** fields), but there is a problem:
When several values are entered in search bar, if among these values 2 or more values are from the **same** field, even though the request matches with any of therapists, the search returns NULL.
Example:

*Therapist:*

```
[
  {
     "first_name": "Thomas",
     "skills": [
            {
                "id": "0658374347844fd7b69b3d033e17f9b1",
                "title": "Self-reflection"
            },
            {
                "id": "2c6ab46d4ebb4cb1a46c934f0c30ebbe",
                "title": "Patience"
            },
            {
                "id": "f22c8210dd4d4a3299ea8887c1da7c30",
                "title": "Flexibility"
            }
        ],
        "counselling_areas": [
            {
                "id": "5fb0c57ced4c41129829b3620076dda4",
                "title": "Body dysmorphic disorder"
            }
        ]
]
```

If I write in search bar "Thomas self-reflection patience", it will return me NULL even though everything matches with the therapist in database. How can I fix this? Is there any solution or I need to write my own search filtering function from the scratch?

Comment: what if you just write `Thomas`? Or `patience`

Comment: Following docs _If multiple search terms are used then objects will be returned in the list only if all the provided terms are matched._ https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/ I do not know how it is related to mulitple fields you can filter by but  I would start with taking a look at sql query that is triggered by request with multiple search words applied.